# Fill gaps in a topology proof

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, boolean-algebra, filters

I am trying to fill gaps in a proof located at [this page](https://ncatlab.org/toddtrimble/published/topogeny) by Todd Trimble.

I prefer the proofs by citing "Stone Spaces" book (and maybe Wikipedia).

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be sets.

- Todd claims that topologies on $\beta X_1 \times \ldots \times \beta X_n$ are precisely compact Hausdorff spaces on $\beta X_1 \times \ldots \times \beta X_n$. How does this follow? I suppose we need first prove 
  that topologies on $\beta X_i$ are precisely compact Hausdorff spaces on $\beta X_i$, and second prove that finite products of compact Hausdorff spaces are precisely compact Hausdorff spaces. Right? Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_space seems to claim that boolean algebras are equivalent to  compact totally disconnected Hausdorff spaces (not to compact Hausdorff spaces), so do I misunderstant something?

Comment: Where on the nlab page is the claim in question?  You seem to have paraphrased it, and I can't understand your paraphrase or find the original.

Comment: @EricWofsey Todd claims that $\Sigma_i\mathscr{P}X_i$ is isomorphic to topology on $\beta X_1 \times \ldots \times \beta X_n$, he also claims that this is equivalent to compact Hausdorff spaces (for $n=2$). Do I misunderstand something? See proposition 4.10 and below

Comment: Where does he say anything is "equivalent to compact Hausdorff spaces"? (I don't even know what you think that phrase would mean...)

Comment: @EricWofsey "a topogeny from $X$ to $Y$ is precisely a relation from $\beta X$ to $\beta Y$ in the pretopos of compact Hausdorff spaces"

Comment: That contains the words "compact Hausdorff spaces" but otherwise has basically nothing to do with what you said...are there some words in that sentence you don't understand and whose meanings you are assuming?

Comment: @EricWofsey Maybe I misunderstand what is the pretopos of compact Hausdorff spaces? I have rather vague understanding what is a pretopos (and would need to consult a reference to understand it). What do I misunderstand in the Todd's proof?

Comment: @EricWofsey I assumed Todd means "a topogeny from $X$ to $Y$ is precisely a relation from $\beta X$ to $\beta Y$ which is a compact Hausdorff space". Wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is correct (it's not exactly the meaning as stated but it is equivalent).  I don't know how you got from that to "topologies on $\beta X_1 \times \ldots \times \beta X_n$ are precisely compact Hausdorff spaces on $\beta X_1 \times \ldots \times \beta X_n$" though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "relation from $\beta X$ to $\beta Y$ in the pretopos of compact Hausdorff spaces" is just a subobject of the product $\beta X\times\beta Y$ in the category of compact Hausdorff space.  Concretely, that's just a subspace of $\beta X\times \beta Y$ which is itself a compact Hausdorff space, or in other words just a closed subspace of $\beta X\times\beta Y$.

There is no assertion being made here about general topologies or compact Hausdorff spaces.  All that is being said is that there is a natural bijection between topogenies from $X$ to $Y$ and closed subspaces of $\beta X\times\beta Y$.

Comment: I completely don't understand how "Hausdorff" appears in the proof. I want to understand the entire proof. Please help

Comment: and the word "compact"

Comment: What "proof" are you even talking about?

Comment: proposition 4.10 and below

Comment: Well, Proposition 4.10 does not even mention compact Hausdorff spaces anywhere.  The only relevance of compact Hausdorff spaces really is that $\beta X$ happens to be a compact Hausdorff space, and so they are a convenient category to talk about things in.

Comment: But Todd seems to say that it is isomorphic to the set of **all** compact Hausdorff space on this set. Why?

Comment: and I don't know why it is compact and why Hausdorff

Comment: hm, now I think I misunderstood Todd. Now I feel that he mean that topogenies from $X$ to $Y$ correspond to _some_ compact Hausdorff spaces on $\beta X\times\beta Y$ not _all_ of them. How to understand it correctly?

Comment: It means exactly what I wrote in the answer: topogenies from $X$ to $Y$ correspond to _subspaces_ of $\beta X\times\beta Y$ that are compact Hausdorff spaces.  Since $\beta X\times\beta Y$ is itself a compact Hausdorff space, those are just the closed subspaces.

Comment: But does the reverse hold? If a subspace of $\beta X\times\beta Y$ is compact Hausdorff, does it follow that it corresponds to a topogeny? If yes, why?

Comment: Yes, because it is a closed subset of $\beta X\times \beta Y$.

Comment: The question is why every closed subset of $\beta X\times \beta Y$ corresponds to a topogeny. It is the main thing I do not understand

Comment: Well, that is what Proposition 4.10 says.

Comment: 1. It says "isomorphic to the topology of its spectrum". Accordingly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras the spectrum is "compact totally disconnected Hausdorff space" not just "compact space". Where "totally disconnected has gone"? 2. I realize that (at least finite) product of compact Hausdorff spaces is compact Hausdorff. But how to go backward from $\beta X\times\beta Y$ being compact Hausdorff to $\beta X$ (and $\beta Y$) being compact Hausdorff?

Comment: A compact totally disconnected Hausdorff space is in particular a compact Hausdorff space.  Since $\beta X$ is the spectrum of $PX$, it is compact Hausdorff.

Comment: And the last question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras speaks about closed bases but Todd about closed subsets (=subspaces) not bases, as representations of a boolean algebra element. Why?

Comment: ...Because Todd is talking about all the closed sets, not just a basis for them?  They're talking about totally different things: the Wikipedia article is defining the topology on $S(B)$, and Todd is stating a theorem about the closed subsets of one particular space.

Comment: They are both talking about the topology of the spectrum, that is about representation of a boolean algebra element. Why one tells about closed sets and another about $S(B)$?

Comment: Where after all Todd gets the concept of "closed set" in his writing?